# PHPUnit does not find a class

Tags: php, composer-php, phpunit

I am working on a new tokenizer class for PHP_CodeSniffer. This also requires making a new Standard since the valid tokenizers are specified within each standard.

My new classes are using the same namespaces as the “sibling” classes from the original codebase.

If I use composer to install my project, and run `phpcs`, the auto loader seems to pick up my new classes just fine. PHP_CodeSniffer will load my tokenizer by calling:

```
$className = ‘PHP_CodeSniffer\\Tokenizers\\’ . $type;
$class = new $className(<stuff>);
```

Similarly, my custom standard has a use statement for a class in the original codebase. When running `phpcs`, no error are thrown.

When I try to run a test file through phpcs in a unit test, I get an error that my custom sniff file is unable to find the class in the use statement. My guess is this is auto-loading related. The bootstrap.php file for phpunit requires `__DIR__ . ‘/../vendor/autoload.php’`.My project composer.json has:

```
“autoload”: {
  “psr-4”: { “PHP_CodeSniffer\\”: “src\” }
},
“autoload-dev”: {
  “psr-4”: { “PHP_CodeSniffer\\Tests\\”: “tests\” }
}
```

Is there an issue with using the same namespace as the original code? With registering the same namespace to a different location in composer? Why does it work in runtime but not in testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out PHPUnit has its own custom bootloader. When I added a `require_once()` for that in my PHPUnit bootloader, it loaded successfully. Thanks to a user on the PHP subreddit.